# Custom permalink rewrite rules - how do I fix this?

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, permalinks, advanced-custom-fields, slug

I've spent about 6 days trying to research and decipher a way to have a custom post type's permalink change based on an Advanced Custom Fields(ACF) selection element. From my experiments, it's half worked. all articles have correct permalinks that lead to the correct page setups. sadly, it seems these custom pages themselves just 404 when visited.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? I've done my very best to get this far, but I don't known enough to get that final boost to finish this system.

Here's the relevant coding segments:

```
register_post_type(
    'articles', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Articles',
            'singular_name' => 'Article',
            'add_new' => 'Add new article',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit article',
            'new_item' => 'New article',
            'view_item' => 'View article',
            'search_items' => 'Search articles',
            'not_found' => 'No articles found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No articles found in Trash',
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'revisions',
                        'thumbnail'
        ),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'community/articles/%category_type%'),
        'menu_icon' => "dashicons-groups",
        'capability_type' => array('article','articles'),
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
    )
);
```

---

```
function rem_articles_rewrite( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post($id);
    if ( is_object( $post ) ){
        $ptype=get_post_type($post);
        //Check the correct post type
        if($ptype=="articles"){
            //Here you need to get the value of the field, you have the ID of the post
            $post->ID and assign the value to $category variable
            $category=get_field('category',$post->ID);
            if( $category ){
                return str_replace( '%category_type%' , $category , $post_link );
            }
        }
    }
return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'rem_articles_rewrite', 1, 3 );
```

The intended URL is something like https://website.com/community/articles/theory/-ARTICLE_SLUG-/
Any ideas what I've messed up on, or what needs adding?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you flush rewrite rules? Also you rewrite rules array code is redundant- you already defined a pattern when you registered the post type.

Comment: I did, yes. But, it's still 404ing when I visit the link. The permalink in the slug section of the article is 100% correct, it's just that visiting it causes 404 errors.

I see. I'll remove the latter bit of code from my setup, then! But doing so hasn't fixed the issue. It's still throwing a 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom rewrite tags have to be added before they can be used in permalinks, otherwise WP will not be able to parse those rules.

```
function your_init_function(){
    add_rewrite_tag( '%category_type%', '([^&]+)' );
    // register your post type....
}
```

Comment: Perfect! that fixed it instantly. Thanks a lot! :)